# Dynamically Generated Text box and live Search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to add text box dynamically using JQuery and make live search for each text box.. it is working, but i want to add text box in table and each table row contain five column. each column contain one text box except first column. First column contain check box. Specially text boxes should be different Ids.... I tried with below code.. but not working properly....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            x=0;
            $('#btn-addrow').on('click', function () {
                $('#tbl-data').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><div class="search-box"><input type="text" id='txt'+x+''><div class="res"></div></div></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
               x++;
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function () {
                    /* Get input value on change */
                    var term = $(this).val();
                    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".res");
                    if (term.length) {
                        $.get("../svr/aj-live-search.php", {query: term}).done(function (data) {
                            // Display the returned data in browser
                            resultDropdown.html(data);
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultDropdown.empty();
                    }
                });

                // Set search input value on click of result item
                $(document).on("click", ".res p", function () {
                    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                    $(this).parent(".res").empty();
                });
            })
        })
```

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062337/how-to-make-live-search-for-dynamically-genarated-text-box)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make live search for Dynamically genarated Text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062337/how-to-make-live-search-for-dynamically-genarated-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly there is Some syntax error in append section, than How can you use live search with keyup event in button with click event, So i simplified your code please try this , hope it works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
x=0;
$('#btn-addrow').on('click', function () {
    // alert('Do what ever');
    $('#tbl-data').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><div class="search-box"><input type="text" id="txt'+x+'"><div class="res"></div></div></td><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>');
    x++;

})
   // Set search input value on click of result item
   $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function () {
    /* Get input value on change */
    var term = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".res");
    if (term.length) {
        $.get("../svr/aj-live-search.php", {query: term}).done(function (data) {
                        // Display the returned data in browser
                        resultDropdown.html(data);
                    });
    } else {
        resultDropdown.empty();
    }
   });

   $(document).on("click", ".res p", function () {
    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent(".res").empty();
   });
```

});